# Cannot find where a subdomain website is registered to

Tags: dns, subdomain

I'm a new hire at a company as a webmaster who is tasked with setting up a new blog.
The company has an existing blog, but absolutely zero record of who registered it, what dns the blog was registered with, or what CMS was used to create it.

I have a new blog, and would like to use the same url to put it live, which is blog.example.com, but blog.example.com is being used by the other blog at the  moment.

Our IT department searched the domain records for our example.com domain, and do not see any blog.example.com record at all in the list, so it is registered somewhere else perhaps? Or is our IT department simply missing something very obvious.

We own example.com, so it should be pretty simple to find the subdomain under it, right?

Comment: What IP address does the subdomain point to? That should answer your question.

Comment: Pinging the subdomain simply responds with lb.wordpress.com - so knowing that it's a wordpress site is good, but we still need to find the dns information so we can debug this domain.

Comment: Well that's helpful for knowing it's a WordPress.COM site (not a WordPress.org CMS site). I'd look into how wordpress.com handles setting up custom subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

Mevius' comments lead me to the answer. wordpress.com is a host, wordpress.org is self-hosted. Since this is a wordpress.com blog, it's as simple as logging in with the account hosting the old blog, and looking at the wordpress.com domains. Thanks Mevius.